# How can I import an addon into a Blender script?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to import an addon into a Blender script

Is this possible, are there any tutorials about it?

Comment: Something like `from io_scene_3ds.import_3ds import load_3ds` to use `load_3ds(filepath, context, IMPORT_CONSTRAIN_BOUNDS=10.0, IMAGE_SEARCH=True, APPLY_MATRIX=True, global_matrix=None)` code from the import 3ds addon? or do you want to enable the addon in a script?

Comment: i would like to enable to addon in a script @batFINGER

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are addon utilities available in 2.77/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py which you can import into your script.

Here is an overkill example, lists all addons and then tries to enable addons named `['mesh_looptools','mocap_madness','goose']`

```
import bpy
from addon_utils import check, paths, enable

def get_all_addons(display=False):
    """
    Prints the addon state based on the user preferences.
    """
    import sys
    paths_list = paths()
    addon_list = []
    for path in paths_list:
        bpy.utils._sys_path_ensure(path)
        for mod_name, mod_path in bpy.path.module_names(path):
            is_enabled, is_loaded = check(mod_name)
            addon_list.append(mod_name)
            if display:  #for example
                print("%s default:%s loaded:%s " % (mod_name, is_enabled, is_loaded))                
    return(addon_list)
#print all the addons and show if enabled and default
addons = get_all_addons(True)
#enable dependencies
addon_dependencies = ['mesh_looptools','MocapMadness','goose']
for addon in addon_dependencies:
    if addon in addons:
        is_enabled, is_loaded = check(addon)
        if not is_enabled:
            print("%s enabled" % addon)
            enable(addon)
    else:
        print("Error Dependency %s missing" % addon)
```

Answer from https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?234219-Check-if-Add-On-is-enabled-using-Python&p=1970462&viewfull=1#post1970462

Mainly only need

```
    is_enabled, is_loaded = check(addon)
    if not is_enabled:
        print("%s enabled" % addon)
        enable(addon)
```

Comment: okay, so would i have to change addon to what the addon is called

Comment: Yes,  like "mesh_looptools" for Mesh Loop Tools

Comment: how would i use the addon after it was enabled

Comment: Depends on the addon.  Addon foo_bar may register an operator "foo_bar" which you would call using  `bpy.ops.foo.bar()`

Comment: What im wanting to do is open a 3d view addon from python, ho would i do that

Comment: @batFINGER I'm trying to download the latest mocap_madness addon. Could you please share a link of the addon. I found this https://github.com/batFINGER/batFINGER-blender-addons/tree/master/mocap_madness and downloaded it then compressed it as zip file then installed it, but I can't find it in the addons list.