# Undo Frequently Crashes Blender 2.83

Tags: add-on, error

I'm trying to debug an issue where seemingly randomly Blender 2.83 will crash while Undoing (and maybe redoing too) is causing Blender to immediately crash. I'm guessing it's related to one of my many installed addons. Below are details about my situation, as well as a list of installed addons:

Details:

- Custom startup file
- CUDA enabled
- Global Undo enabled
- More than enough RAM, sometimes it crashes on my first undo, even immediately after opening Blender
- Crashing does not generate a crash log, there is no error given, Blender simply closes.
- Running Blender from the Debug console, the error saved in the log is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION which is some non specific error that doesn't help.
- Lots of addons installed, though most all claim support for 2.8+
- Running installed Blender 2.83 (not portable) on Windows 10, 64bit, NVIDIA GPU, AMD CPU, latest drivers and OS. 16gb of ram that is no where near being used up when crashing.
- Crashing happens often, only when Undoing/Redoing, noticed in most workspaces (layout, modeling, shading, sculpting, etc)

```
Enabled add-ons:
=====================================

io_anim_bvh (version: (1, 0, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py)
io_curve_svg (version: UNKNOWN, path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_curve_svg\__init__.py)
io_mesh_ply (version: (1, 1, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_mesh_ply\__init__.py)
io_mesh_stl (version: (1, 1, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py)
io_mesh_uv_layout (version: (1, 1, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_mesh_uv_layout\__init__.py)
io_scene_fbx (version: (4, 20, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py)
io_scene_gltf2 (version: (1, 2, 75), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py)
io_scene_obj (version: (3, 8, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py)
io_scene_x3d (version: (2, 2, 5), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\__init__.py)
cycles (version: UNKNOWN, path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\cycles\__init__.py)
measureit (version: (1, 8, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\measureit\__init__.py)
precision_drawing_tools (version: (1, 4, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\precision_drawing_tools\__init__.py)
add_curve_ivygen (version: (0, 1, 5), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\add_curve_ivygen.py)
add_curve_sapling (version: (0, 3, 4), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\add_curve_sapling\__init__.py)
ant_landscape (version: (0, 1, 8), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\__init__.py)
archimesh (version: (1, 2, 2), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\archimesh\__init__.py)
amaranth (version: (1, 0, 8), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\amaranth\__init__.py)
space_view3d_brush_menus (version: (1, 1, 8), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\space_view3d_brush_menus\__init__.py)
space_view3d_spacebar_menu (version: (1, 9, 4), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\space_view3d_spacebar_menu\__init__.py)
lighting_dynamic_sky (version: (1, 0, 6), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\lighting_dynamic_sky.py)
sun_position (version: (3, 1, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\sun_position\__init__.py)
lighting_tri_lights (version: (0, 1, 4), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\lighting_tri_lights.py)
materials_library_vx (version: (0, 6, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\materials_library_vx\__init__.py)
materials_utils (version: (2, 2, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\materials_utils\__init__.py)
mesh_f2 (version: (1, 8, 4), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\mesh_f2.py)
mesh_tools (version: (0, 3, 6), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\mesh_tools\__init__.py)
mesh_looptools (version: (4, 7, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\mesh_looptools.py)
mesh_snap_utilities_line (version: (5, 9, 19), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\mesh_snap_utilities_line\__init__.py)
mesh_tissue (version: (0, 3, 25), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\mesh_tissue\__init__.py)
node_wrangler (version: (3, 36), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\node_wrangler.py)
space_view3d_align_tools (version: (0, 3, 4), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\space_view3d_align_tools.py)
object_boolean_tools (version: (0, 4, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\object_boolean_tools.py)
object_carver (version: (1, 2, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\object_carver\__init__.py)
object_fracture_cell (version: (0, 2), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\object_fracture_cell\__init__.py)
object_scatter (version: (0, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\object_scatter\__init__.py)
magic_uv (version: (6, 2, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\magic_uv\__init__.py)
system_blend_info (version: (0, 3, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\system_blend_info.py)
HOps (version: (0, 9, 8, 5, 24), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\HOps\__init__.py)
Boxcutter (version: (0, 7, 1, 6, 5), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\Boxcutter\__init__.py)
building_tool-master (version: (1, 0, 0), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\building_tool-master\__init__.py)
DECALmachine (version: (1, 9, 2), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\DECALmachine\__init__.py)
uv-spectrum_2_80 (version: (1, 0), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\uv-spectrum_2_80.py)
pro_lighting_studio (version: (1, 2, 6), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\pro_lighting_studio\__init__.py)
add_mesh_extra_objects (version: (0, 3, 6), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\add_mesh_extra_objects\__init__.py)
MESHmachine (version: (0, 6, 11), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\MESHmachine\__init__.py)
Extreme PBR 2_82 v3_3_31 (version: (3, 3, 31), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\Extreme PBR 2_82 v3_3_31\__init__.py)
materials_x_creator (version: (1, 0, 0), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\materials_x_creator\__init__.py)
extra_lights (version: (1, 0), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\extra_lights\__init__.py)
layer_painter (version: (1, 2, 1), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\layer_painter\__init__.py)
Anti-Tile-280-v1-53 (version: (1, 53), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\Anti-Tile-280-v1-53\__init__.py)
AntiSeam (version: ('1', '0'), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\AntiSeam\__init__.py)
SuperTexture280v1-72 (version: (1, 72), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\SuperTexture280v1-72\__init__.py)
NodeCustomBuilder (version: (0, 0, 50), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\NodeCustomBuilder\__init__.py)
True-Terrain PRO (version: (3, 0, 1), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\True-Terrain PRO\__init__.py)
true_grass (version: (2, 0, 3), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\true_grass\__init__.py)
fspy_blender (version: (1, 0, 3), path: C:\Users\robpr\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\fspy_blender\__init__.py)
```

Does anyone know how I can disable my addons and re-enable groups of them easily? Having to scroll through the full list of addons to find my addons to re-enable/disable is too time consuming and tedious. I need a way to quickly divide my installed addons into two groups, test the group and see if it crashes, if so divide the group again and see if it continues to crash, repeat until I have narrowed down the culprit. Considering it crashes randomly when undoing (sometimes I can undo a hundred times with no problem, sometimes it crashes on the first undo, sometimes it will repeatedly crash undoing the same thing, sometimes it won't crash when doing that thing, very random).

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi. If the question is more focused on how to disable batches of add-ons I suggest editing the title and focusing the content on that. If the question is mainly about the crash then this should be reported to the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/) and this question will likely be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know how much it applies to your case, but `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` is a common error code given in relation to conflicts with windows UAC (Don't know how much this is a bug with windows or not). Try running Blender as an administrator and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58208/15543  an access violation is often caused by trying to access a reference to an object since removed.  `.