# Custom error message on addon enable?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

I'm writing an addon (let's call it MyAddon) which depends on other addon (say DependencyAddon).
If I install DependencyAddon first and then install MyAddon all works fine. Otherwise I get an ImportError, which is obvious.

Is it possible to show custom error message "Install DependencyAddon first" instead of traceback?

Comment: Do you know about the try/except Python statement?

Comment: Could enable / disable if  already installed  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58202/how-can-i-import-an-addon-into-a-blender-script  Else Answer here,  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213191/15543  possibly also answers here somewhat.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Yeah, I know about try/except. But in this case I'm getting even bigger traceback because of "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks! The second link is quite useful.